# React-router StaticRouter mutating prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to wrap my head around this API for react router StaticRouter which is used for server side rendering:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/static-router

But it puzzles me that the prop can be mutated inside the subcomponents. Isn't it passed as prop following a HOC pattern and resulting in a mutated prop antipattern in React?